# RabbitMQ Stream Perf Test Tool Grafana Dashboard

Tags: rabbitmq, grafana, rabbitmq-stream

RabbitMQ provides the following official dashboards: https://grafana.com/rabbitmq

They also provide a perf-test tool dashboard (nice!), unfortunately I can not find the ones for the stream-perf-test tool.

I have enabled the prometheus port with the corresponding flag, however as the metric names are differing, I can not reuse the official perf-test dashboard.

Is there a dashboard for the stream-perf-test tool? Or does someone else has one for me?

I already searched on the official RabbitMQ website and grafana.com for a suiteable dashboard.

Thanks and BR,

Philipp

Comment: https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/14798-rabbitmq-stream/ ?

Comment: That's the dashboard for monitoring streams on the RabbitMQ instance. I am looking for one that uses the metrics of the strem perf TOOL, which has a dedicated Prometheus endpoint exposing end 2 end latency metrics and others.

Comment: I am afraid that we don't have it at the moment. Any contribution is welcome